# How can i set up a private web app on Azure using an App Service Environment

Tags: web-services, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app and a web service (which will be uploaded to Azure as an web app). How can i make my web service private (not accessible to the public, only accessible by the web app). Apparently you're able to do it with an App Service Environment but there isn't much documentation on it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between App Service and App Service Environment (ASE) is that App Services run on a pre-built, shared tenant hyper scaled web farm, but ASEs are purpose built (on demand) web farms provisioned directly in your subscription that must be attached to a VNET.  Because you can attach your ASE to a VNET, you can then apply Network Security Groups (NSG) to the VNET to prevent/allow traffic to flow to the ASE.

Here is the page describing how to add the layered security to your ASE once you've built it:

[Layered Security Architecture with App Service Environments](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-layered-security/)

So with ASE you get the deployment/monitoring/management features of App Services, but with the network layer control of a VM.

Comment: Thanks Russel. The diagram helped me understand what i have to do.

Comment: Good stuff - can you mark the answer to close this off then please?

Comment: I've got it all set up, i allowed VNET to my Web-service but my web app is unable to communicate with it. they're both in the same VNET but the Security group is only connected to the web service

Comment: oh and my web service is in a app service environment. but my web app is in a normal app service

Comment: If the web app is in the "normal" app service, then it's in a separate vnet from your ASE's web service.  You need to use the "Networking" configuration option on the web app to connect it to your vnet - then your web app will be able to talk to anything in the vnet, including your ASE endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make my web service private (not accessible to the public, only accessible by the web app).

Network Security Groups could be used to control network traffic rules at the networking level, we could apply Network security group to the subnet to let Network security group act as a firewall in the cloud. @Russell Young has shared us a good article about setting up Network security group, you could read it. And you could check [this blog](https://vincentlauzon.com/2015/12/21/using-network-security-groups-nsg-to-secure-network-access-to-an-environment/) that explained securing network access using Network Security Groups.

Besides, it is easy to implement a custom authentication to prevent unauthenticated client from accessing to your Web service at application layer. For example, we could use SOAP headers for authentication. Web service client credentials would be passed within the SOAP header of the SOAP message when the client want to access to Web service, and then Web service will validate SOAP header, if it contains the authentication credentials, the client will be authorized to access to the Web service.

You could check [Implement Custom Authentication Using SOAP Headers](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/8ef97c/web-service-in-asp-net-security-by-soap-authentication-pa/).